# Props in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

How to pass props in React.js via `react-router-dom`? How do I do this with `Route` or `NavLink`? I want to pass props from one subpage to another.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />
  <Route
    path="/addcustomer"
    element={<AddCustomer addCustomer={() => addCustomer} />}
  />
</Routes>
```

Comment: This is a [widely covered topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+react+router+dom+props).